# meteor blaze renderwithdata pass document to template with autoform

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I have the following template:

```
<template name="editUser">
    {{> quickForm collection="Users" doc=doc id="editUserForm" type="update"}}
</template>
```

And I render it in a popover div using:

```
  Blaze.renderWithData(Template.editUser, data, target);
```

I would like to pass the doc variable required  by the quickform and don't really understand the data parameter.

I tried to use the following as data:

```
var data = {doc: Users.find({_id: feature.getId()}).fetch()};
```

but this does not seem to be the way to pass a document in the variable doc.

i could not find how to properly use it and would like to avoid a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I need to pass the cursor and not the data itself. So it works when I replace:

```
var data = {doc: Users.find({_id: feature.getId()}).fetch()};
```

with

```
var data = {doc: Users.find({_id: feature.getId()})};
```